# How to query and show a field in an array for each mongodb record?

Tags: mongodb

I have the below data in a mongo database

```
{
    "_id": "100",
    "Color": "Green",
    "data":[{"Name":"John"}]
}
{
    "_id": "101",
    "Color": "Green",
    "data":[{"Name":"Andy"}]
}
{
    "_id": "102",
    "Color": "Blue",
    "data":[{"Name":"Paul"}]
}
{
    "_id": "103",
    "Color": "Blue",
    "data":[{"Name":"Jimi"}]
}
{
    "_id": "104",
    "Color": "Blue",
    "data":[{"Name":"Lucy"}]
}
{
    "_id": "105",
    "Color": "Red",
    "data":[{"Name":"Aron"}]
}
```

I would like to retrieve a set of results as below, where each 'Name' in the array is shown as a 1 to 1 view against the 'Color' field.

```
{
    "Color": "Green", "Name": John
    "Color": "Green", "Name": Andy
    "Color": "Blue", "Name": Paul
    "Color": "Blue", "Name": Jimi
    "Color": "Blue", "Name": Lucy
    "Color": "Red", "Name": Aron
}
```

I have read the documentation about groups but not sure how to write the query to get the results in the format shown above?

Comment: there are couple of things wrong in the schema example you gave. 
1 - Duplicate id - you have duplicate _id which aren't allowed
2 - Invalid JSON - Your data field is invalid. Do you mean to say array ob objects like [{Name: Aron}] or an object with those properties likes {Name: Aron}. Please fix this issues first so that we can help you.

Comment: @SamipSuwal I have corrected the data structure by introducing the Color field. It is this field that now would be displayed instead of "_id". It is indeed an array of Objects, and corrected fhe format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok you want to do this query then

```
db.getCollection('test').aggregate([
{
    $project: {_id: 0, Color: 1, Name: "$data.Name"} //_id field is included by default and we need to supress it
}, 
{
    $unwind: "$Name" //without this the Name will be embedded
}, 
{
    $sort: {
        "Color": 1
    }
}])
```

Here, we first pass along the documents with only Color and Name with **$project**.

Since Name was inside data array, it is embedded inside an object, so we deconstruct it using **$unwind**. Which will make it top level property. 
Please note that if data had multiples items, it would "unwind" all of them.

Then lastly we will use **$sort** to sort our data according to Color.

Does this help?

**Update after Neil Lunn's comment**

As Neil pointed out, since we only have 1 element in the array. We could use [$arrayElemAt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/), and we won't have to have the $unwind pipeline stage.

Here is the updated code,

```
db.getCollection('test').aggregate([
{
    $project: {_id: 0, Color: 1, Name: {$arrayElemAt: ["$data.Name", 0]}} //_id field is included by default and we need to supress it
}, 
{
    $sort: {
        "Color": 1
    }
}])
```

Comment: How about [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) instead of including an `$unwind` stage, given consideration that all array items only have one element.

Comment: definitely we can use $arrayElemAt as you suggested if we are guaranteed to have only 1 element in the array, which seems to be the case here. Which will take out our need to use $unwind. Thanks for commenting.

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect! One change I made was changed the Name to a ResultofName, which distinguished from the original column